# How do I access the minimized production code for an ExtJS app in my development environment?

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I'm using ExtJS 6.2 and when we develop in our local enviros we're access the unminimized code through https://localhost:8443. Once we deploy to our production enviros, the ExtJS code is minimized and sometimes we have errors that don't occur in our development enviros and we can't seem to find it until going through the deploy process.

I'd like to be able to test the production build locally in my development enviro but can't seem to find a way to access that built, minimized code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how your server and build process is set up.

If you are using sencha cmd build in server and you have no build customization, you can access the production build using this URL:

http://localhost:1841/build/production/~Insert_Application_Name~/

Comment: You a freaking life saver! Thank you. The only difference in my app was really changing the path to /build/production/~appname~/ and keeping our direct hostname. The localhost and port mentioned in your answer didn't work in my case. Thank you so much!